# $\frac13n<\sqrt[n]{n!}<\frac12n$

Tags: inequality

> Prove that for every $n\in N_{\ge6}$ the inequality $\frac{1}{3}n<\sqrt[n]{n!}<\frac{1}{2}n$ holds.

My approach was to use induction. I started with the LHS and I noticed that the left inequality holds for every integer that is greater or equal to $1$. The base case is obvious. Now assume that $\frac{1}{3}k<\sqrt[k]{k!}$ holds for some $k > 1$, and let's consider the $n = k+1$ case.
So we want to prove that $\frac{1}{3}(k+1)<\sqrt[k+1]{(k+1)!}$ or $[\frac{1}{3}(k+1)]^{k+1}<(k+1)!$ or $(1+\frac{1}{k})^k<\frac{3^{k+1}k!}{k^n}$, now I wanted to use the fact that $2\le (1+\frac{1}{n})^n < 3$, so if I can prove $\frac{3^{k+1}k!}{k^n}<3$ I am done, but here the inequality goes in a wrong way. What am I missing? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of the letters $k$ and $n$ is a bit confusing. It seems to me that the chain of inequalities goes in the right way.

For the induction step, we have to show that
$$n^n<3^n n!\implies (n+1)^{n+1}<3^{n+1}(n+1)!$$
We have that
$$(n+1)^{n+1}=(n+1)n^n\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n<(n+1)3^nn!\cdot 3=3^{n+1}(n+1)!$$
because $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n<3$ for $n>1$.
Similarly, $2^nn!<n^n$ implies
$$(n+1)^{n+1}=(n+1)n^n\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n>(n+1)2^nn!\cdot 2=2^{n+1}(n+1)!$$
because $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n>2$ for $n>1$.